# How to add my custom UIViewController in react native App

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I want to implement Face detection in react native. I want to add CameraViewController Demo in react native. CameraView controller source code is here: https://github.com/googlesamples/ios-vision/blob/master/FaceDetectorDemo/FaceDetector/CameraViewController.m

```
 import Foundation
@objc(SampleViewManager)
class SampleViewManager : RCTViewManager {
  override func view() -> UIView! {
    //    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Sample" bundle: nil];
    //  //
    //    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
    return vc.view;
  }
}
```

but error occured:Could not load the "Camera" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier

kindly help me how to implement Face detection in react native.

Comment: did you find a solution to this

Comment: yes, I helped from here: git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera